# Start a C# WinForms application for all loged in users

Tags: c#, winforms, scheduled-tasks

I created a WinForms application that is being start by a scheduled task under the `SYSTEM` user. The only problem is that it's running in the background.

Is it possible to write a wrapper around the program to get the logged in user and bring it to their desktop?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScheduledTaskTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The terminology of this post isn't very clear and kind of a little ambiguous

Comment: @MichaelRandall That's quite common with X/Y problems.

Comment: `running in the background`, `bring it to their desktop` what exactly do you mean

Comment: @Filburt exactly

Comment: @StuiterSlurf You might want to specify what your task's trigger is and problem you are trying to solve by running it as System.